# Can ImageMagic's commands like convert be trusted on untrustable input files?

Tags: imagemagick, code-injection

I wonder if it is ok (apart from the fact it is done million times daily...) to feed ImageMagic's `convert` command with user-uploaded files?

Obviously, ImageMagic has a large attack front, as it is capable of loading tons of formats and thus using vast amounts of code processing input data.

Excessive CPU or memory consumption do no harm, as this can be kept under control by simple means (for example by `ulimit`). Abitrary file access or runing injected code with network access however must be prevented by `convert`. Can we expect this?

Are there procedures to follow for the ImageMagic authors that would provide a feasable amount of security against such exploits?

Comment: Additionally: Would `convert` remove malicious input? Eg. If an attacker does not target `convert` itself, but embed malicious data, could we use `convert` to not pass through data that is unknown to it? Like removing any metadata except valid data needed to display an image itself.

Comment: The -strip option will remove most of the metadata before writing an output file.

Comment: Thats cool, thanks for the hint.+

Comment: Also the ImageMagick makers himself state that they are into security issues and ran a lot of checks on security related issues... Plus ImageMagick has some kind of ressource control via the  `-limit` option (which do not work very well, as they limit only certain caches) and `ulimit` would provide strong limits. Still there would be some malicous tricks left, as `convert` definetively needs access to some files to operate...